# Running Macro through Python and still able open new excel sheets

Tags: python, vba, excel

Just curious if anybody knows why this happens.

I have python code that triggers and runs a macro in a workbook. The macro can take several hours to run. If I run the macro without the use of Python, my workbook is open and for the time it takes the macro to run I am unable to use excel until the macro is completed.

What I noticed when I run the macro via Python, the sheet doesn't open and not only that but I am able at the same time python runs the excel macro I can actually open up other workbooks.

How does this happen? and where is the python triggered workbook macro run from? It doesn't even pop up in the Task Manager?

If anybody knows how this happens I would love to know!

Regards,
T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is creating an instance of Excel, setting `Application.Visible=False` and doing its thing there. It's actually tying up the UI thread of that instance, but you can't see it. During that time, you are able to open another instance of Excel by clicking on the Start Menu link (or double clicking a file), and you can use the UI thread of that instance to do other things.

When *you* open Excel, by default, it sets `Application.Visible=True`. Your macro is running in that instance and blocking the UI. Since you're using the default UI instance, it's blocked and you don't get the option to create another instance.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. Now out of curiosity could I actually code Python to run multiple macro driven workbooks at the same time?

Comment: _Could_ you? I'm sure. Will it work? I haven't a clue... One sure way to find out!

Comment: Awesome, Thank you!